# Does MongoRepository utilize MongoDB cursor?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45493993/10255450):

```
@Query("{}")
Stream<Alarm>  findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
```

I'm trying to understand how would that work for a large collection? Does this utilize MongoDB cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All find queries use cursors..